# Parallel work in javascript, how to return in the right order?

Tags: javascript

My class is to execute parallel tasks in accordance with the code specified parameter *parallelJobs*.

I need to return responses in the right order.

example code([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbbNaK?editors=0012)):

```
class Parallel {
  constructor(number) {
    this.parallelJobs = number.parallelJobs;
    this.results = [];
    this.currentJobs = 0;
    this.counterCalls = 0;
    this.countJobCalls = 0;
  }

  pushArray(value) {
    if (this.results.length && this.results.length !== this.counterCalls) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.pushArray(value, callNumber)
      }, 50);
    } else {

      this.results.push(value);
      this.counterCalls++;
    }

    this.currentJobs--;
    return true;
  }

  runFunc(runConsole) {
    this.currentJobs++;
    runConsole(this.pushArray.bind(this));
  }

  job(runConsole) {
    this.countJobCalls++;
    if (this.currentJobs < this.parallelJobs) {
      this.runFunc(runConsole);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.job(runConsole);
      }, 500);
    }

    return this;
  }

  done(onDone) {
    this.lastJobCall = this.countJobCalls;
    if (this.results.length && this.lastJobCall === this.results.length) {
      onDone(this.results);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.done(onDone)
      }, 50);
    }

    return true;
  }
}

var runner = new Parallel({
  parallelJobs: 4
});

runner.job(step1)
    .job(step2)
    .job(step3)
    .job(step4)
    .done(onDone);

function step1(done) {
  console.log('step1');
  setTimeout(done, 100, 'step1');
}

function step2(done) {
  console.log('step2');
  setTimeout(done, 10, 'step2');
}

function step3(done) {
  console.log('step3');
  setTimeout(done, 150, 'step3');
}

function step4(done) {
  console.log('step4');
  setTimeout(done, 50, 'step4');
}

function onDone(results) {
  console.log(results);
}
```

There should return an array ["step1", "step2", "step3", "step4"] what best way this can be achieved in this example?

Comment: use a promises to control the ordering.

Comment: As an aside - your `job` function should either always run the function synchronously *or* always run the function asynchronously, never a mixture of both. Otherwise, you run the risk of [releasing Zalgo](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony).

Comment: How to use a promises for this example class? I have no idea:(